# Adding "vscode" option like how typing "cmd" works in Windows File Explorer path bar

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry, windows-11, microsoft-file-explorer

[image: Windows File Explorer path bar]
By typing `cmd` or `powershell` to the Windows File Explorer path bar (the photo above), you can open cmd or powershell in the current path your File Explorer is in.

But how about `vscode`? Can I add this `vscode` to the path bar keywords so I can type `vscode`, press enter and quickly open Visual Studio Code in the directory the File Explorer is in? If so, how? Some registry magic?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that by typing `code.cmd .`, you can do the thing that I wanna do exactly.

`code.cmd .` is too long? Got you covered!
Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin` (This is default path, yours might be different)

Copy the `code.cmd` to `code.bat`

And you can now type `code` to the path bar of the File Explorer and do the samething easier :D

P.S.: You can also change `code.bat` to something else like `vscode.bat` and you can type `vscode` to the path bar to do the samething :DDD